# Windows Phone 8 emulator with ARM NEON

Tags: visual-studio, arm, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, neon

When developing an application for Windows Phone 8 on ARM, is there a way to simulate or emulate the app if it has ARM NEON assembly? I.e., is the code compiled for x86 and run natively, or is it there a way to actually emulate an ARM NEON machine?

Comment: And that's a shame. [There's a petition](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/4138536-make-the-emulator-emulate-the-arm-cpu-like-in-win) for an ARM emulator for Windows Phone. Please sign.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone 8 emulator is an x86 environment, so ARM code isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

There's no emulator, but there's a free remote device access service, courtesy of Nokia, at http://rda.cellulardata.com/devices . You can't debug, but you can watch it run. Bake in some visible reporting into your app, publish it as a beta, download to a device and enjoy.

Since it's a beta, it won't be available via store search; you'd have to type in a URL. A link shortening service or a forward page on your own web space would come in handy here.

You have to explicitly designate your own Live ID as a beta tester account for a beta project. The Store doesn't recognize the "I'm downloading my own app" situation.

Answer (score 0):

...let me add that the Phone devices are still ARM, so if you want to run on both device and emulator, you'll need to compile your native code for both ARM and x86.